# PHP 401 status returns -1

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, http-status-code-401, http-response-codes

I'm trying to return `401` response status in my `AngularJS` app. But in console that I see, it returns **-1**

What I use in php:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
http_response_code(401);
```

Also in codeigniter:

```
$this->output->set_header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
$this->output->set_status_header(401, "my status text");
```

[image]

It works fine in status codes like: 200 , 205, 206 etc.

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a cross origin request from XMLHttpRequest.

In a simple case, this means that the server has to grant permissions to the JavaScript before the browser will give the data to the JavaScript.

This is not a simple case. You are making a complex request which requires [preflight authorisation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

Before making the POST request you want to make, the browser is making an OPTIONS request asking for permission.

The server is responding to the OPTIONS request with a 401 response. The error message tells you this explicitly:

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

The browser is then refusing to make the POST request at all.

Consequently the status of the POST request is -1.

You need to respond to the OPTIONS request with a 200 status (and appropriate CORS permissions headers). Then the browser will make a POST request (which you can reject with a 401 if you like).

Comment: (A lesson here is that when you have four lines of output in the console, you shouldn't focus your attention solely on the *last* one)

Comment: Woow! Thank you. You're right. As mentioned in your link : `It sets custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header such as X-PINGOTHER)` , when I cleaned this header `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization`, I could able to get **401** response code. So what I can I do?

Comment: @vahidnajafi — As I said, change the server side code so it always responds OK (with appropriate CORS headers) to the OPTIONS request.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day. Finally I did what you said in server with this: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
   http_response_code(200);
   exit();
  }`